# spring process POST data - annotate the right controller

Tags: java, forms, spring, request

I'm having problems with configuring spring MVC to process form POST data in the right controller. I've got an `add` action which is going to add a new record to the database.

After the form is submitted, I'm getting 404 error (`http://localhost:8084/lyricsBase/song/submit.html`), so I guess that I've made something wrong in routing the form submission.

This is my controller code:

```
public class SongController extends MultiActionController {

    [...]
    @RequestMapping(value = "/song/submit.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submit(@RequestParam("song") Song song) throws Exception {
        HashMap model = new HashMap();
        model.put("song", song);
        // or do something better here...
        return new ModelAndView("t.edit", model);
    }
```

and this is the view form tag:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="song" action="submit.html">
```

The code of my application is available on [github](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/lyricsBase/tree/5a00efb733a87a9b3c8fa7dda084176ff7cb33b5). Here are the important files: [the form view](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/lyricsBase/blob/5a00efb733a87a9b3c8fa7dda084176ff7cb33b5/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/edit.jsp), the [controller](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/lyricsBase/blob/5a00efb733a87a9b3c8fa7dda084176ff7cb33b5/src/main/java/com/blogspot/symfonyworld/lyricsbase/controller/SongController.java) (the class is a multi controller, since I don't want to create a separate file for each action) and [servlet configuration](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/lyricsBase/blob/5a00efb733a87a9b3c8fa7dda084176ff7cb33b5/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lyricsBaseApp-servlet.xml).

Don't know if it matters, but I'm using tiles for the view layer (and logical view names are used in [tiles.xml](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/lyricsBase/blob/5a00efb733a87a9b3c8fa7dda084176ff7cb33b5/src/main/resources/tiles.xml)).

Besides, I don't fully understand how spring routing works. Until now, I'm defining a mapping in the servlet xml, but don't know if it is a good approach...

Comment: Please add the relevant code snippets to your question.

Comment: @KeesdeKooter important code snippets added.

Comment: If you map your request using the @RequestMapping annotation there is no need to map it in your servlet.xml.

Comment: Check in your browser debug tools which url is called when submitting the form. Is it /song/submit.html?

Answer (score 1):

What is the posted value of song ? I'm not sure if Spring transcribes or deserializes posted data into an object/ entity. 
You could try changing;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/song/submit.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submit(@RequestParam("song") Song song) throws Exception {
```

into

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/song/submit.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submit(@RequestParam("song") String song) throws Exception {
```

and see if thats picked up.

Another way, is to read the parameter from the request object;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/song/submit.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submit(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

Object song = request.getParameter("song");
```

Gl !

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change `@RequestParam("song")` to `@RequestBody`

Answer (score 0):

If your application URL is :

```
http://localhost:8084/lyricsBase/song/submit.html
```

Request mapping should be like (remove first '/' in mapping) :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "song/submit.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submit(@ModelAttribute("song") Song song) throws Exception {
}
```

And form tag in jsp should be :

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="song" action="song/submit.html">
```